# Getting org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: this.getChromeWindowFromDocumentWindow(...) is undefined on window maximize on FF for Selenium 2.49.0

Tags: java, firefox, selenium

I keep getting the exception while trying to maximize the window.-

`org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: this.getChromeWindowFromDocumentWindow(...) is undefined`

I am also getting this issue with **2.49.1**. This happens only when I call the `driver.manage.window.maximize()` method. If I comment this out then the issue doesn't raise its ugly head.

Has anybody else come across this issue? Any idea what could be causing this?

BTW, this is happening on firefox only.

Comment: which version of FF? it could be a compatibility issue. Try downgrading FF

Comment: @bozzmob have already tried downgrading down to FF v42.0. The same FF version works fine with selenium 2.45.0 though.

Answer (score 1):

Update your Firefox. I found same problem. I solved this problem to update Firefox V42.0 to V44.0.
Or 
Remove or comment out below code
 //driver.manage().window().maximize();

Comment: still facing the issue even after upgrading to FF44 and Selenium 2.50.0.

Comment: I solved the problem to upgrade to firefox 44.0.2,and selenium-java-2.52.0

Answer (score 1):

I too got the same error on firefox, I resolved it passing the URL first and maximize it

Answer (score 0):

I've just updated Firefox to V44.0.2 and using Selenium webdriver v 2.52.0 and still seeing the same exception if I use driver.manage().window().maximize();
However, when this driver.manage().window().maximize(); is commented out, no exception was thrown

Answer (score 0):

As for me, the issue was fixed only for the following configurations:
1) FF 43.0.4; Selenium.WebDriver 2.53.0. 2) FF 43.0.4; Selenium.WebDriver 2.52.0.
Newer versions of FF do not work properly, the discussed exception appears.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is resolved by adding the code below before window maximize

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(200, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.manage().window().maximize();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(200, TimeUnit.SECONDS);   
driver.get(url);
driver.manage().window().maximize();
```

Having "driver.manage().window().maximize();" after loading the URL does not throw this exception

Answer (score 0):

this.driver.get("www.google.com");
this.driver.manage().window().maximize();

Use the above code and the issue will be resolved:)
Also, the issue is not version specific, I tried upgrading and downgrading my firefox version, it wont help.